# Converting Python 3 libraries to be used in 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm following a tutorial which is coded in Python 3 and the author uses

```
from urllib import parse
```

which gives me an error.

I've tried using Google and reading up about the library but can't seem to find equivalent. All my code for project is in 2.7 so I would prefer not to have to move over 3 just for this little bit.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: There is a program called 3to2.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm currently looking at tutorials on how to use 3to2, but i have a couple questions. Would i install this into my Pycharm as a library? and does it work automatically in correcting 3to2 code?

Comment: No; you'd use it on command line. Anyhow, if you're fairly new to python and this is your own project, I suggest you skip over Python 2 altogether and migrate now. That is, if we're talking about 1000 lines of code; not 10000 or 100000 in production use

Comment: 2to3 will help you forward-porting your code.

Comment: unfortunately in this situation the project is on a time scale and migrating over to 3 would cause more issues than good at current time, I have been able to work out the 2.7 equivalent for most other libraries I've been using to this point but now I'm at a head scratching point but there should see a simple conversion for it, in the past I've known others to be a difference of a word or even just a letter

Answer (score 1):

Urllib has been restructured in python 3. What was [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) in python 2, is now urllib.parse (in python 3). So just use urlparse. You can even do this:
`import urlparse as parse` and the rest of the code should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Make your code Python 2 compatible without losing Python 3 compatibility.
You could use a library like [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/), but for just this single import, this may suffice:

```
try:
    from urllib import parse
except ImportError:
    import urlparse as parse
```

Note that you may have "invisible" compatibility issues though. For example, standard division in Python 3 is always floating pointing division, even between two integers, while in Pyhton 2 this is not. Thus, while not likely with code that deals with URL parsing, you may want to add

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of the Python 3 code as well.

---

Generally, I recommend writing and using Python 3 code, making it Python 2 compatible where needed, but not *converting* it to Python 2 (i.e., not using the 3to2 or 2to3 tools, but use e.g. six or some try-except imports).

This way, that code is already Py3 ready, but still works with Py2.